# Ruby - Extra punctuation in file when using regex and csv class to write to a file

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

I'm using regex to grab parameters from an html file.

I've tested the regexp and it seems to be fine- it appears that the csv conversion is what's causing the issue, but I'm not sure.

Here is what I have:

```
mechanics_file= File.read(filename)
mechanics= mechanics_file.scan(/(?<=70%">)(.*)(?=<\/td)/)

id_file= File.read(filename)
id=id_file.scan(/(?<="propertyids\[]" value=")(.*)(?=")/)

puts id.zip(mechanics)

CSV.open('csvfile.csv', 'w') do |csv|
 id.zip(mechanics) { |row| csv << row }
end
```

The puts output looks like this:

```
2073
Acting
2689
Action / Movement Programming
```

But the contents of the csv look like this:

```
"[""2073""]","[""Acting""]"
"[""2689""]","[""Action / Movement Programming""]"
```

How do I get rid of all of the extra quotes and brackets? Am I doing something wrong in the process of writing to a csv?

This is my first project in ruby so I would appreciate a child-friendly explanation :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) returns an `Array` of `Array`s (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `scan(pattern)` → `array`
>
> Both forms iterate through *str*, matching the pattern (which may be a `Regexp` or a `String`). For each match, a result is generated and either added to the result array or passed to the block. If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, `$&`. **If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group**.
>
> ```
> a = "cruel world"
> # […]
> a.scan(/(...)/)      #=> [["cru"], ["el "], ["wor"]]
> ```

So, `id` looks like this:

```
id == [['2073'], ['2689']]
```

and `mechanics` looks like this:

```
mechanics == [['Acting'], ['Action / Movement Programming']]
```

`id.zip(movements)` then looks like this:

```
id.zip(movements) == [[['2073'], ['Acting']], [['2689'], ['Action / Movement Programming']]]
```

Which means that in your loop, each `row` looks like this:

```
row == [['2073'], ['Acting']]
row == [['2689'], ['Action / Movement Programming']]
```

[`CSV#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-3C-3C) expects an `Array` of `Strings`, or things that can be converted to `String`s as an argument. You are passing it an `Array` of `Array`s, which it will happily convert to an `Array` of `String`s for you by calling [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_s) on each element, and that looks like this:

```
[['2073'], ['Acting']].map(&:to_s) == [ '["2073"]', '["Acting"]' ]
[['2689'], ['Action / Movement Programming']].map(&:to_s) == [ '["2689"]', '["Action / Movement Programming"]' ]
```

Lastly, `"` is the string delimiter in CSV, and needs to be escaped by doubling it, so what actually gets written to the CSV file is this:

```
"[""2073""]", "[""Acting""]"
"[""2689""]", "[""Action / Movement Programming""]"
```

The simplest way to correct this, would be to [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) the return values of the `scan`s (and maybe also convert the IDs to `Integer`s, assuming that they are, in fact, `Integer`s):

```
mechanics_file = File.read(filename)
mechanics = mechanics_file.scan(/(?<=70%">)(.*)(?=<\/td)/).flatten

id_file = File.read(filename)
id = id_file.scan(/(?<="propertyids\[]" value=")(.*)(?=")/).flatten.map(&:to_i)

CSV.open('csvfile.csv', 'w') do |csv|
 id.zip(mechanics) { |row| csv << row }
end
```

Another suggestion would be to forgo the `Regexp`s completely and use an HTML parser to parse the HTML.